# How to debug a stack process being 'killed'?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm compiling a haskell file with

```
$ stack ghc --resolver lts-12.5 --package raw-strings-qq myscript.hs
```

and execute it with

```
$ ./myscript
Killed
$
```

on my Ubuntu machine. I get `Killed` as an error message and nothing else.
How can I debug this? Does this mean the process takes up to much memory? Are there other possible sources of error?

Comment: 1. you should include the output as displayed in the terminal. 2. you can use `strace` but that will not show you stuff on the Haskel level, but only on the syscall level. 3. you should change you title so people know your problem concerns Haskell

Comment: 1. I've edited my question accordingly
2. thanks, I'll look into that
3. Isn't that what the tags are for?

Comment: 3. you are right, of course, however if an observer understands the question at a glance maybe your chances will be higher that he might give you an answer instead of skipping the question. But again, you are right.

Comment: Also, maybe you want to include the code of `myscript.hs`? You should reduce it as much as possible to only include the few lines that trigger the "kill".

Comment: To determine if this is due to the OOM killer, check `dmesg`

Answer (score 0):

The response you get from terminal as `Killed` is because you didn't give some commands:

1. I use online IDE called Replit, so at the start it doesn't load needed libraries for you, you have to load manually:

   ```
    ghci -o main main.hs
   ```
2. Sometimes, it automatically loads `Main`, sometimes it doesn't. So, if you don't see such thing like below, then you have to do it manually as well:

> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, interpreted )
> Ok, one module loaded.
> *Main>

```
   :l main
```

Maybe, it doesn't directly answer your question, but I got same exception like yours and dealt with it in that way. Well, same exception has the same problem (I guess)?